# Python selenium scrape - particular informations from block of code

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I need scrape (and collect) some live sport stats from local betting [site](https://www.nike.sk/live/prehlad). Im using python for that. So, how can I add to python dataframe actual state? In my code I have a variable "games_container ", but I dont know how extract particular informations (sport, league, team A, team B, result...). Thanks for any help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import time
import requests
from time import gmtime, strftime, localtime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numbers
import matplotlib

from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

DRIVER_PATH = 'C:\\executables\\chromedriver.exe'

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

driver.get("https://www.nike.sk/live/prehlad")

time.sleep(20)


games_container = soup.find_all(class_='sport-content-div sport-content clearfix')
```

Expectet output (shape of pandas dataframe):

[image: Expected output]

.................................
EDIT:
Is possible make for loop who extract from this part of code: "home shorten label 1", "game result" and "home shorten label 2"?

[image: Site code]

................................. EDIT_2:
When I use:

```
driver.get("https://www.nike.sk/live/prehlad")
time.sleep(15)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html5lib')
games = soup.find_all('div',{'data-atid':'live-sport-box'})

for game in games:
    print(game.find('h2').getText())
    labels = game.find('h4',{'class':'game-content-title'}).findChildren('span',recursive=False)
    label1 = labels[0].getText()
    label2 = labels[2].getText()
    result = labels[1].getText()
    print(f"{label1} : {label2} : {result}")
```

In my output is only 1 match (1 row) for each sport:

```
Tenis  (21)Podľa turnaja/súťažePodľa času
 Cristian J.A. : Krunic A.  : 0 - 0
Futbal  (4)Podľa turnaja/súťažePodľa času
 Shaanxi Changan : Chengdu Rongcheng  : 0 - 0
Hokej  (4)Podľa turnaja/súťažePodľa času
 MHC Torpedo : MHC Arlan  : 4 - 1
```

How can I print (iterate) all matches for all sports?

Comment: Can you share the example of data ? which data did you mean for let's say 1st record ? I know you have written `sport, league, team A, team B, result...` but let me know for first record what will be these values ?

Comment: Thank you. I updated my answer with expected output

Comment: The website has data for other sports as well, so Goals A and Goals B won't be there in those cases. It's tricky.

Comment: Yes, there is many sports, so I need in output column "Sport". I like scrape all sports

Comment: I can use Score A and Score B, not Goals...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
driver.get("https://www.nike.sk/live/prehlad")
time.sleep(15)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html5lib')
games = soup.find_all('div',{'data-atid':'live-sport-box'})
for game in games:
    print(game.find('h2').getText()) # Prints the heading of the sports
    print(game.find('ul').getText()) # Prints all the details of that particular sport
```

To extract particular data separately into a variable like the teams and results make use `Regex`. [Supporting link](https://newbedev.com/beautiful-soup-if-class-contains-or-regex)

Those details are in an `span` within a `h4` tags. We can use `findChildren()` for the same.
To get all the Teams and their results try like below:

```
for game in games:
    print(game.find('h2').getText())
    labels = game.find('h4',{'class':'game-content-title'}).findChildren('span',recursive=False)
    label1 = labels[0].getText()
    label2 = labels[2].getText()
    result = labels[1].getText()
    print(f"{label1} : {label2} : {result}")

    # Or Iterate over labels:
    # for label in labels:
    #     print(label.getText())
```

```
Tenis  (4)Podľa turnaja/súťažePodľa času
 Caruso S.
0 - 0
Fritz T. 
Futbal  (1)Podľa turnaja/súťažePodľa času
 CD Guadalajara ž.
2 - 0
CF Pachuca ž.
```

Comment: Thank you. I m going to try it now.

Comment: Pls, can you look to my edited question?

Comment: @314mip - I have updated the answer for the same. Also add what you have tried When update the question.

Comment: Thank you. If I try second for loop, python return error: " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findChildren' "

Comment: @314mip - I have tried the same. It dint throw any error for me. Have updated with sample output.

Comment: I hope you have patience with me... I update my question. If I use last for loop I see only one match for each sport (1 match for tenis, 1 for football... but on web site is much more actual matches)

Comment: @314mip - Okay - What have you tried to solve that? update the same in the question.